# BASH: Assign '&' to variable NOT as string

Tags: bash

I wanted to conditionally run a command as a background or foreground process, so I wrote something like this:

```
test $some_var; bg_suffix=&
long_command $bg_suffix
```

it doesn't work because bg_suffix is always empty whether it's been assigned or not.

But

```
test $some_var; bg_suffix="&"
long_command $bg_suffix
```

doesn't work either because now bg_suffix is interpreted as a string.

Any ideas how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You might find this informative: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Here is how to do it without using a quote-breaking eval

```
inBackground () {
  t=$1
  shift
  if $t; then
    "$@"&
  else
    "$@"
  fi
}
```

This lets you do something like:

```
inBackground false echo '$$'
inBackground true sleep 4
```

This gets around the problem that all the eval-based solutions have: new and sometimes impossible quoting rules. For example, try to pass the `'$$'` through eval.  Because `true` and `false` are not significant to the parser they can be in variables and things will still work.

Of course, if you wanted shell metachars to work (say, you redirect i/o) then eval is better, or you need to define a procedure for the command, and if you define a procedure, you problem is solved:

```
complicated_command () {
    sleep 3
    echo replace this with something complex
}
do_background=true
$do_background && (complicated_command&) || complicated_command
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
if [[ ${somevar} ]] ; then
    long_command &
else
    long_command
fi
```

or, if it *is* a long command you don't want to have to enter twice:

```
long_command=insert your big honking command here
if [[ ${somevar} ]] ; then
    ${long_command} &
else
    ${long_command}
fi
```

Just as an aside, I hope you're aware that the command sequence:

```
test ${condition}; x=2
```

will set x to 2 regardless of the `test` results. You may have meant to write:

```
test ${condition} && x=2
```

Comment: Yes It's a long command otherwise I would go with your first snippet.
Thanks for pointing out my mistake in using "test" command.

Answer (score 2):

did you try

```
eval (long_command $bg_suffix)
```

using bg_suffix="&"

Comment: I get an error with this. I think you may need double quotes around the string being eval'ed. ??

Comment: I also got an error with this but

    eval long_command $bg_suffix 

worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why I am not able comment, but anyway

test $some_var; bg_suffix="&"

would cause bg_suffix to be set regardless of the result of test.